# How to style one column in a stacked bar?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want all bars in the last column to have a certain color.
With the following code, only the topmost bar is styled (see http://jsfiddle.net/kalyfe/gvczd6nx/):

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['week', 'apples', 'bananas', {role: 'style'}],
    ['last week', 5, 17, ''],
    ['this week', 9, 22, ''],
    ['projection', 11, 27, 'color:#ddd;']
]);
```

How else would I apply styling to a column in a stacked bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets the style for apples bar, like the style for the bananas bar

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['week', 'apples', {role: 'style'}, 'bananas', {role: 'style'}],
    ['last week', 5, '', 17, ''],
    ['this week', 9, '', 22, ''],
    ['projection', 11, 'color:#ddd;', 27, 'color:#ddd;']
]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gvczd6nx/3/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set the style for each column independently then give the color value as @R3tep has mentioned but if you want it for group of columns then may be try like this:

```
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['week', 'apples', 'bananas','oranges'],
        ['last week', 5, 17, 11],
        ['this week', 9, 22, 12],
        ['projection', 11, 27,10]
    ]);

  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart')).
    draw(data, {
        title: "Weekly fruit intake",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        isStacked: true,
        colors: ['#0f0', '#ddd', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
    });
}
```

see **demo** [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gvczd6nx/4/)

also see this:https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart